# How to select a table by a td's id

Tags: jquery, selector

How to select a table by a td's id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
$("#myId").closest("table");
```

but I 'm not completely sure -- can you clarify or provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

Using [jQuery closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Using the following example code

```
<table id="test">
    <tr>
        <td id="one">one</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="two">two</td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function(){

   var table = $("#one").closest('table');

});
```

See [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/swaff/Jvkvh/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the closest() function.

```
$('#td-id').closest('table');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LpPNA/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
$('td#id').closest('table')
```